# Android Studio : Missing SDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I am on windows 7, i have installed all the java environnement.
JAVA_HOME is working.
When i try to install android studio, he display me a window that said :

> Missing SDK

So it's impossible to create or open a project. I have nothing on AppData folder. 
I saw all the posts about this question on stackoverflow, nothing helped me.

I try everything, do you have an advice or an idea.

Thx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install SDK tools component while installing Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604948/unable-to-install-sdk-tools-component-while-installing-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY, I had the same exact problem downloading the latest software 3.0.1 for windows. This process works, before hitting open a new project, go to "configuration" at the bottom of the screen find settings for SDK manager and route the separately downloaded SDK files location to the file. Then any other additional SDK selections you need you can simply click on the box and select it and it will download. No other answers I found helped me except this one. Very simple solution but not so simple if your a first-time user learning this program.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK folder was empty for C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Android\SDK

For displaying hidden AppData or Local subfolder: Tools, Folder Options, View, Advanced Settings, Files and Folders, select option Show hidden files, folders, and drives.

The SDK folder should contain the following subfolders:

- build-tools.
- emulator.
- extras.
- patcher.
- platforms.
- platform-tools.
- sources.
- tools.

Downloaded the zip file to create the tools subfolder
from link, sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip
of section, Command line tools only, Platform Windows
within URL, https://developer.android.com/studio
Zip file name: sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip
Copied this zip file into C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Android\SDK
Unzipped this file, which created tools subfolder.

Downloaded zip file to create the platform-tools subfolder 
from link, Download SDK Platform-Tools for Windows, 
within URL, https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html
Zip file name: platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip
Copied this zip file into C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Android\SDK
Unzipped this file, which created platform-tools subfolder.

Open Android Studio and follow prompts.  Other subfolders will be created automatically.

Answer (score -2):

you need to download android sdk [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip)

and extract it and give its location in android studio **settings > system settings > android sdk**.
Hope this will help.