# Unable to install SDK tools component while installing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I've just downloaded latest Android studio from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html (683MB). While installing this it doesn't gives me an option to select Android SDK which is a very important component. Once I finish the setup with whatever components shown in the screen shot, it says Android SDK is missing. Please find the attached screenshot for the same.

I thought installing Studio will give me all the required tools but this doesn't give me SDK.

I'm installing this for Appium Mobile Automation testing.[image: Android Studio Installer]

Answer (score 4):

If you installed Android Studio and still SDK is not available under below path

```
%USERPROFILE%\appdata\Local\Android\sdk
```

then delete current Android Studio project folder `(%USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudio3.0)` and relaunch Android Studio, now this time android studio will popup for sdk.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Go to configure option at right bottom corner as show in the image.
    [image: 1]

Click edit option next to "Android sdk location". If you have an existing sdk folder then select that or you will have an option to download the latest sdk.

Comment: Can't we just download Android SDK? I tried from official site but it doesn't contains platform-tools folder, it contains only tools folder so I'm not sure whether this can be useful or not

Answer (score 0):

The SDK folder was empty for C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Android\SDK

For displaying hidden AppData or Local subfolder: Tools, Folder Options, View, Advanced Settings, Files and Folders, select option Show hidden files, folders, and drives.

The SDK folder should contain the following subfolders: • build-tools. • emulator. • extras. • patcher. • platforms. • platform-tools. • sources. • tools.

Downloaded the zip file to create the tools subfolder from link, sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip of section, Command line tools only, Platform Windows within URL, https://developer.android.com/studio Zip file name: sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip Copied this zip file into C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Android\SDK Unzipped this file, which created tools subfolder.

Downloaded zip file to create the platform-tools subfolder from link, Download SDK Platform-Tools for Windows, within URL, https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html Zip file name: platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip Copied this zip file into C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Android\SDK Unzipped this file, which created platform-tools subfolder.

Open Android Studio and follow prompts. Other subfolders will be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by setting the directory path to another directory rather than inside "Program file"